# Why np.resize() out_place, while ndarray.resize() in_place?

Tags: python, class, numpy

According to my understanding, with classes 
`instance.method(parameters)=class.method(instance,parameters)`, so it's just a notation difference.
But `np.resize(ndarray)` changes out_place, while `ndarray.resize()` changes in_place.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but `numpy` isn't the *class*, it is the module. You want `numpy.ndarray` as the class. Observe:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: arr = np.array([1,2,3])

In [3]: np.ndarray.resize(arr, (3,1))

In [4]: arr
Out[4]:
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
In [5]: np.ndarray.resize(arr, (3,))

In [6]: arr
Out[6]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

So, `numpy.resize` is just a module-level function, that returns a *new array* instead of modifying the array in-place.